# ASP.NET Empty Web Site template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, web

I'm trying to find ASP.NET Empty Web Site in Visual Studio 2016 template list, but I can't. It is still exist there or I'm able to use only ASP.NET Web Application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open VS2015 > File > New Project > Select ASP.NET web application (.NET framework)

[image: new project options]

Then press OK to continue. On next template window, select Empty option-

[image: Empty template option]

See if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To create "ASP.NET Web Site" projects in Visual Studio 2016 you need to install the "Additional project templates (previous versions)" ASP.NET Component.

It probably gets missed as this option is only visible if you click on the ASP.NET workload and is not listed on the "Individual components" tab!

[See Image 1 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37DWt.png)

After installing the component, the templates are now present:

[See Image 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK4lO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just create an empty folder then "Open Website" option from the startup page.

Answer (score 0):

To create an Empty web site, you need to do the following :

Open VS2015 > File > New Web Site > Visual C# > ASP.Net Empty Web Site